# Computation of a Drazin inverse

Tags: na.numerical-analysis, matrices, linear-algebra

I need to compute the Drazin inverse $A^D$ of a singular M-matrix $A$, i.e., a matrix in the form $A=\lambda I -P$, where $P$ has nonnegative entries and $\lambda$ is the spectral radius (Perron value) of $P$. I already know the right and left eigenvectors $v$ and $u^T$ of $P$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$ (that is, the vectors in the left and right kernel of $A$).

1) Is there a Matlab subroutine around for computing Drazin inverses? I can't seem to find any, so I had to create my own (which is probably very inefficient)

2) Is there a way to exploit the knowledge of the two nullspaces (and the fact that they are 1-dimensional) to speed up this computation?

Comment: Have you seen http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/S0895479891228279 already?

Comment: @J. M. I don't have access to the full-text from my institution, but from the abstract it does not seem related to what I'm doing. I already know the Perron right and left eigenvectors, I need to compute the group/Drazin inverse

Comment: By the way, an answer to question (ii) for the Moore-Penrose pseudo-inverse instead of the Drazin inverse would be most welcome as well.

Comment: Hey, I don't know if you've already found an answer to this, but it looks to me that the results of http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BFb0120751 and http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/0131057 might be applicable to your problem.

Comment: The first link is a "DOI not found". I'll check the second, though, thanks!

Comment: Eep, sorry for not checking that first DOI! Here's the first one: http://www.springerlink.com/content/u528652t80v96515/

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to Matlab, and the matrix is not gigantic 
you can use the following to calculate the Drazin inverse:

1. Determine the index of $A$, i.e, does $\mathrm{rank}(A^k)  =  \mathrm{rank}(A^{k+1})$
2. Solve the linear system   $A^{k+1} X  =  A^k$
3. Use the fact that  $A^D$, the Drazin inverse, is given by

$$A^D =  A^k  X^{k+1}$$

Jim Shoaf,  N. C. Central University

Comment: Thanks! Could you please expand on how to solve that singular linear system? If I am not missing some crucial detail, it could even be $0X=0$, for instance in the case when `A=[0 1; 0 0]`.

Comment: 1) One way to try to solve A^(k+1)*X = A^k in Matlab is X = A^(k+1) \ A^k , where these powers of A are stored as Ak2 and Ak 2) Another approach to calculating Ad is the Schulzz (Hoteling) iteration: X = .0001*A repeat X = 2*X - X*A*X (until convergence -- sometimes divergence!!)

Answer (score 1):

This one might have some pertinent leads:

http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0024379585902356